# Timer is delayed when many Tasks are running

Tags: c#, timer, task

I'm using a Timer to calculate an action progress, but if there are many running tasks, the timer is delayed.

Below is my timer class:

```
public class TimingAction
{
    private const int ProgressUpdateIntervalDefault = 500;

    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public int ProgressUpdateInterval { get; set; }

    public event Action<double> ProgressUpdated;

    private readonly Timer progressTimer = new Timer();
    private readonly Timer scanTimer = new Timer();
    private readonly Stopwatch timeWatch = new Stopwatch();

    public TimingAction()
    {
        ProgressUpdateInterval = ProgressUpdateIntervalDefault;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // Stop progress after duration time
        timeWatch.Restart();

        scanTimer.Interval = Duration;
        scanTimer.Elapsed += (o, e) => Stop();

        // Send progress notification
        progressTimer.Interval = ProgressUpdateInterval;
        progressTimer.Elapsed += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (ProgressUpdated != null)
            {
                ProgressUpdated((double)timeWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / Duration);
            }
        };

        timeWatch.Start();
        scanTimer.Start();
        progressTimer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        scanTimer.Stop();
        progressTimer.Stop();
        timeWatch.Stop();
    }
}
```

And below is my test class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int wt, ct;
        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out wt, out ct);
        Console.WriteLine("Before starting tasks : worker thread {0}, completion thread {1}", wt, ct);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int taskID = i;
            //Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TestTask(taskID));   
            var t = new Thread(() => TestTask(taskID));
            t.Start();
        }

        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out wt, out ct);
        Console.WriteLine("After starting tasks : worker thread {0}, completion thread {1}", wt, ct);

        var action = new TimingAction();
        action.ProgressUpdated += action_ProgressUpdated;
        action.ProgressUpdateInterval = 100;
        action.Duration = 1000;
        action.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("After starting timer : worker thread {0}, completion thread {1}", wt, ct);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void action_ProgressUpdated(double obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("progress {0:00}%", obj*100);
    }

    static void TestTask(int taskID)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //Console.WriteLine("Thread ID: {0}, Task {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, taskID);
        }
    }
}
```

When I use Thread class to run TestTask method, the progress works well, result is:

```
Before starting tasks : worker thread 1023, completion thread 1000
After starting tasks : worker thread 1023, completion thread 1000
After starting timer : worker thread 1023, completion thread 1000
progress 16%
progress 21%
progress 33%
progress 44%
progress 54%
progress 65%
progress 76%
progress 87%
progress 98%
```

But when I use Task class to run TestTask method, the timer Elapsed call is delayed, result is:

```
Before starting tasks : worker thread 1023, completion thread 1000
After starting tasks : worker thread 1019, completion thread 1000
After starting timer : worker thread 1019, completion thread 1000
progress 105%
progress 199%
```

What is reason of this delay and anyway to resolve it? However, the delay only happens at the beginning 2 seconds, if I increase the duration to 10s, the progress works well after 2s delay.

The application runs under .Net Framework 4.5.

Comment: It is probably not the timer itself which is delayed. The callback needs to run on a threadpool thread. If they are all busy running other tasks, the callback will be delayed.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: I also think it is related to ThreadPool. But I only run 5 tasks and they are always sleeping, It shouldn't impact the Timer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be certain which type of Timer you're using, because we can't see the using statements at the top... but I'm going to assume that it's the System.Windows.Forms.Timer.

[This Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) explains the differences between timers. Using a System.Timers.Timer may be a better choice here, if you have strict requirements for when the timers are fired.

Comment: Thanks. I tried System.Timers.Timer and System.Threading.Timer, they are the same result.